# Is there a way to download the android 2.3.3_r1 platform source code without repo/git

Tags: android

I'm trying to build the source and flash a phone.
The instructions given in source.android are specific to repo/git and it gives me a error saying Connection refused

Comment: What repository did you try? With what client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android source code repository has been down for a few weeks, and while they are working on getting it back up, there is no timetable for this work to be completed.